# How to remove jpg hyperlinks while writing data to excel sheet in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
df = pd.read_excel("/.../Mastersheet.xlsx")
data = df.loc[:, ["Name", "age", "Bio", "Message", "Profile Pic"]].copy()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'string_to_urls':False})
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Data")
writer.close()
```

in the "Profile Pic" column there are .jpg links that are being hyperlinked in the output excel sheet that i am writing. how do i convert these hyperlinks to text?

the `string_to_urls` doesn't seem to work for .jpg links. any solution for this?

Comment: type here: 'strings_to_formuls':False

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get that. can you explain?